# Apache Tika content issue

Tags: apache-tika

I am having a weird problem with apache tika.When I am getting the filetype first and then parsing I am not getting the content. code:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {

    File file = new File("sample.txt");

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    TikaInputStream objectData = TikaInputStream.get(is);
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

    metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, file.getName());
    TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
    Detector detector = config.getDetector();
    System.out.println("Hello : " + detector.detect(objectData, metadata).toString());

    parser.parse(is, handler, metadata, context);

    System.out.println("File Content :" + handler.toString());

}
```

But when I parse first and then get the filetype i am getting the correct content.code:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException {

    File file = new File("sample.txt");

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    TikaInputStream objectData = TikaInputStream.get(is);
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

    parser.parse(is, handler, metadata, context);

    System.out.println("File Content :" + handler.toString());

    metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, file.getName());
    TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
    Detector detector = config.getDetector();
    System.out.println("Hello : " + detector.detect(objectData, metadata).toString());

}
```

Why is this happening? Is there any way around it? Because I need to manipulate the text according to the given mime type.

Edit:- I think this is a problem with dependency.What are the dependencies required for tika detect to work in terms of referenced library?

Comment: Why are you going `File` -> `InputStream` -> `TikaInputStream` ? Why not [create the TikaInputStream straight from the File object](https://tika.apache.org/1.12/api/org/apache/tika/io/TikaInputStream.html#get%28java.io.File%29)?

Comment: This is a small code example in the package I am creating I have to extract the InputStream from the file object because the file can b kept in servers/local dir/ or any other location.